# kotlinCompilerVersion is deprecated

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I've just started a new Jetpack Compose project using the "Empty Compose Activity" Android Studio (2020.3.1 Canary 14) template, but I'm getting the following warning in my `build.gradle.kts (:app)` file:

> 'kotlinCompilerVersion: String?' is deprecated.

[image]

The deprecation does not provide any information about what to use instead. Should I simply remove this option or do something else?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**`kotlinCompilerVersion`** can be safely removed.
Compose now uses the kotlin compiler defined in your `buildscript`.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.21'
    //....
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

If you are using the `plugins` block (in `settings.gradle` or `build.gradle`)

```
pluginManagement {
    //..
    plugins {
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.21' 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Where did you find out about this?

Comment: @DuncanLuk In Kotlin slack channel. https://surveys.jetbrains.com/s3/kotlin-slack-sign-up

Comment: I'm not sure if this is up to date. Currently, AGP defaults to 1.0.0-beta07 for compose if not provided.

Comment: @pablisco Yes it is up to date. It works for compose `1.0.0` + kotlin `1.5.10` and `1.0.1` + kotlin `1.5.21` with AGP 7.0.0

Comment: My bad, sorry, I was looking at `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion` which is still required and not at `kotlinCompilerVersion` XD